# How is the kinetic energy of the wind transferred onto a lift based wind turbine?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, aerodynamics, renewable-energy

The rotor blades of a lift based wind turbine are shaped like airfoils, so the wind flowing around them creates a lift force which in turn moves them around. From a thermodynamic viewpoint and like answered in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143155/do-wind-turbines-convert-the-kinetic-energy-of-air) kinetic energy is extracted from the wind during this.

But what goes on from a mechanical perspective? How exactly is the kinetic energy of air particles transferred onto the rotor blades via lift? None of the sites I read gave an elaboration on the *how*.

Comment: I posted a new answer to that question, which answer your question as well: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/184730/23679

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is very much analogous to the answer to how aeroplanes fly. See [Physics SE Question "What Really Allows Airplanes to Fly?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290/26076) and the best (IMO) answer is [this one here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/295/26076).

But basically the airfoils, sails or vanes - whatever they may be called - *deflect* the flow of air. They do this by *pushing on the air* and changing the latter's momentum state. By Newton's third law, therefore, the deflected air pushes on the sails, and, for a wind turbine the design is such that this reaction force exerts a torque on the system.

Comment: So lift is (reactive) centrifugal force?